# Implementation of Double Ended Priority Queue using Binary Search Tree/Linked List

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree, deque

I have to implement a Doubly Ended Priority Queue using both Doubly Linked list as well as Binary search Tree.

Main functions should be getMin() and getMax()

1. **Using Doubly Linked List**:
   The idea to get minimum and maximum element in O(1) is to insert small elements at one side of list and greater elements on other side, but there will be problem in insertion of elements everytime(It will not be O(1) then)
   Is there any better way to implement it ?
2. **Using BST**:
   I couldn't understand how will I be able to implement the getMin() and getMax() in BST.

Answer (score 0):

Normal priority queues are usually implemented using heap so we can get the top value easily in O(1) and insert new elements in O(logn). I doubt there is a way to implement a priority queue using doubly linked lists that gets the same asymtoptical complexity, let alone a double-ended priority queue (i can be wrong though). Using a BST we can do both operations in O(logn):

- Insertions and deletions are the same as in your usual BST
- To get the min value, start a traversal at the root and to all the way to the left until the current node has no left child. The last node you visited contains the min value
- To get the max value, start a traversal at the root and go all the way to the right until the current node has no right child. The last node you visited contains the max value

Of course, getMin and getMax will only be O(logn) if the BST is balanced, otherwise it can degenerate to O(n)

Answer (score 0):

> insertion of elements everytime(It will not be O(1) then) Is there any
>   better way to implement it ?

what you are basically trying to do is to search for the first bigger element in order which can't be done in O(1). Linear search *(which means going through elements one by one)* is probably the best way to do this. If you have huge lists and want to focus on efficiency you could use [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) or [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) *(interpolation only works if you know about the probability of the stored keys)* but you can't get closer than **O(loglog(n))**.

> I couldn't understand how will I be able to implement the getMin() and
>   getMax() in BST.

If you're not allowed to add any additional structure to your BST then the only way to get min and max is traversal as **Lucas Sampaio** mentioned already.

However it can be helpful to store a reference to the current minimum and maximum so you can access them faster

Comment: Kind of pointless to do exponential search or interpolation search on a linked list, unless comparisons are hugely expensive in relation to traversals.

Comment: @Jim Mischel You're right, I was only talking about the complicated methods and not the most practical ones